# What is the problem in the given proof of left pseudo inverse of "fat" matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

**Statement:** There exist $S$ such that $ST=I$, where $T\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is full row rank and $m<n$.

**Proof:** Suppose $ST=I$. Since $T$ is full row rank, $(TT^T)$ is invertible. We obtain

$$
STT^T(TT^T)^{-1}=T^T(TT^T)^{-1} \Rightarrow S=T^T(TT^T)^{-1}.
$$

For verification part,

$$
T^T(TT^T)^{-1}T=I,
$$

$$
TT^T(TT^T)^{-1}T=T \Rightarrow T=T.
$$

**Counter example:**

$$
T = \left[ \begin{array}{c}I&0\\0&\mathbb{1}^T\end{array}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{(p+1)\times (p+q)},
$$
where $I$ is of the size $p\times p$ and $\mathbb{1}$ is of the size $q\times 1$. Then,

$$
S = \left[ \begin{array}{c} I&0\\0&\frac{1}{q}\mathbb{1}\end{array}\right].
$$

And,

$$
ST = \left[ \begin{array}{c} I&0\\0&\frac{1}{q}\mathbb{11}^T \end{array}\right]\neq I.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The mistake made is, that the assumption in the statement, that $ST = I$, cannot be correct, since $T$ is the fat matrix.

Comment: Actually $T$ is a "fat" full row rank matrix. So $TT^T$ is invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in reading. I'll delete the post. My mistake.

Comment: @Umar Niazi: Are you fine with the improved answer? Sorry for the confusion in the beginning.

Comment: The statement is surely incorrect. But the question is "Where is the fallacy in the argument of the proof?"

Comment: As already meant, I think the problem is, that you cannot start with "Suppose ST = I" since it is the claim you want to show. And since you already know that it is incorrect, keep in mind, that from a false statement everything can be shown.

Comment: There is no way of knowing truth or falsity of a statement until proven. So, I can start with an assumption that suppose the statement is true, and that assumption holds until I arrive at some contradiction. Apparently there isn't any contradiction. But in fact there happens to be a contradiction in the verification part because $ST=T^T(TT^T)^{-1}T\neq I$. Since $TS=I$, leading to $TST=T$, I concluded that implication holds from both sides.